# React + Redux как правильно отправить action по нажатию кнопки

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Изучаю react и redux. Задача такая: при нажатии на определенную кнопку, загружать мало данных или много. После гугления и чтения SO пришел к такому коду:

Action:

```
export const fetchSmallData = () => {
  return {
    type: 'FETCH_SMALL_DATA',
    payload: axios.get(`URL1`)
      .then(response => {
        console.log("Экшн срабатывает, я появляюсь в консоли :)")
        return response.data;
      })
   }
}

export const fetchBigData = () => {
  // то же самое, только URL другой.
}
```

Reducer:

```
export default function reducer(state=initialState, action) {
  console.log("Редюсер не срабатывает. И я в консоли не появляюсь, а очень хочется :(");
  switch(action.type) {
    case "FETCH_SMALL_DATA":
      return {...state, fetching: true}
    case "FETCH_SMALL_DATA_REJECTED": {
      return {...state, fetching: false, error: action.payload}
    }
    case "FETCH_SMALL_DATA_FULFILLED": {
      return {
        ...state, fetching: false, fetched: true, data: action.payload
      }
    }
    // такая же обработка кейсов для "FETCH_BIG_DATA", "FETCH_BIG_DATA_REJECTED" и "FETCH_BIG_DATA_FULFILLED"
  }
  return state;
}
```

Компонент:

```
class ChoiceButtons extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="btn">
        <p>Загрузить:</p>
        <button onClick={() => this.props.dispatch(fetchSmallData)}>Немного данных</button>
        <button onClick={() => this.props.dispatch(fetchBigData)}>Много данных</button>
      </div>
    );    
  }
}

export default connect()(ChoiceButtons)
```

Проблема: при нажатии на кнопку: экшн срабатывает, запрос отправляется, но редюсер почему-то нет и полученные данные в стор не сохраняются. Если эти же экшены точно так же диспатчить, например, в ComponentDidMount, то все хорошо - стор обновляется.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скобки (вызов функции) пропустили:

```
this.props.dispatch(fetchSmallData())
```

Comment: Спасибо. То, что нужно. На самом деле не пропустил, а подумал, что они не нужны как при передаче обычной функции в onClick.